# How can I select elements only if they have a particular previous sibling?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to made a `$('.x').mouseenter()`,  only if there is  `div.y` is above  and not under!

I have try with `.prev()`, `.prevAll()`,  `.find()`  and many others but  nothing worked!!

```
<div id='cont'>
    <div>toto</div>
    <div class="y">tata</div>
    <div>titi</div>
    <div>tata</div>
    <div class="x">xxx</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this will work `$('.y ~ .x')`

Comment: you want to check immidiate `div.y` or any of `div.y` coming previously `$('.x')`. Please clarify you condition..

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: i said before but not immediatly before  like i try to describe the DIV dom thanks for all the answers .i shall try

Comment: Did you saw my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

[prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/) ?

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

```js
$(".x").mouseenter(function() {
  let checkYAbove = $(this).prevAll('.y').length;
  let checkYUnder = $(this).nextAll('.y').length;
  
  if (checkYAbove) {
    console.log('Your div ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' get a div y above');
  }
  
  if (checkYUnder) {
    console.log('Your div ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' get a div y under');
  }
});

$(".x").mouseleave(function(){
  console.clear();
});
```

```css
div { display: inline-block }
div > div:not(.x) { margin:5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid }
.x:hover { color:red }
.y { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cont'>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="y">Y</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="x">X</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="x">X</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="y">Y</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="y">Y</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="x">X</div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="y">Y</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```